# Checking user input for single, "scalar" value or iterable

Tags: python

I have a function designed for interactive usage that takes either a single "scalar" value as argument or an iterable. The output should match the input. Here is a toy example.

```
def func(x):
    flag = False
    if isinstance(x, int):
        flag = True
        x = (x,)     

    retval = tuple(i**2 for i in x)
    return retval[0] if flag else retval

>>> func(5)
25
>>> func((1,2,3,4))
(1, 4, 9, 16)
```

Question: Is there a more convenient method to check whether the user provided a "scalar" or an iterable? I don't want to rely on checking the with `isinstance`?

I tried with `hasattr(x, '__iter__')`, but this return `True` for "scalar" string input (not covered in the example here).

Comment: A string ("scalar" or not) **is** iterable

Comment: @OhadEytan That's exactly the reason why I cannot use `hasattr(x, '__iter__')`.

Comment: Seems like there is no way to avoid type checking with `isinstance`.